Problem downloading Git repo in Jenkins pipeline
I'm getting a problem downloading a Git repo that happens randomly (sometimes it works sometimes it fails) in a Jenkins pipeline.
I am using the Git plugin in Jenkins (https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) to download a repo and it returns this:
Receiving objects:  95% (1878/1958), 616.23 MiB | 75.39 MiB/s
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0
error: 34205 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

To fix it I've tried to apply a solution found here: fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed. In that post the way of solving the problem is to do a shallow clone and after that to execute a unshallow fetch. When I do this I'm getting the error in the same way as when I use the Git plugin.
I don't know if someone has solved this error in Jenkins. Maybe there is some configuration that I've missed or not applied.

This is most likely a Git issue and not Jenkins one. It is even encountered locally in case of network fluctuations, and if not temporary, will need a check for the Git Repository or the network proxy configuration if required.
